# Table-like data structure in python

Tags: python, data-structures

Is there a data-structure in Python that approximate the behavior of a database table?

My data looks like the following:

id | name | description

1  |  test |  this is a test

The closest I can get is to have a list of dictionaries, but I was wondering if there exists a specific data-structure for that purpose (that, for example, supports sorting or **add**).

Comment: Read about [pandas dataframes](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python)

Comment: Look into Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 2):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is what you are looking for.

You can generate DataFrames from array-like types, like list of dict, dict of list, list of list, np.Array...

Example :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'wololo':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'text':['yay','toto','tat','tata','billy','bill']})
```

The output will look like this

```
    text  wololo
0    yay       1
1   toto       2
2    tat       3
3   tata       4
4  billy       5
5   bill       6
```

It also have useful [I/O Tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html) to read a lot of different files such as Excel, CSV, JSON, etc...

Check also all [the DataFrame methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to manipulate them in the more efficient way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is a python framework, which works with dataframes for data analysis.
Look here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/

Example:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import sys
data = {[name:"test", ...], description:["this is a test", ...]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Should give this:

```
  name description
0 test this is a test
```

Comment: Please flesh this out and give an example, you'll get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

In dictionary you can sort by names and you can also create lists inside dictionaries which can do all the operations you are looking for!! There is also something like Ordered Dictionary which can help you!!
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on an ordered Python dictionnary. It seems like that's what you're looking for. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ttous/Python-dict).

It supports :

```
get(key)
del(key)
set(key, value)
sort()
contains(key)
reverse()
add(another_dictionary)
```

Comment: The problem with ordered dictionaries is that you can only have one key:value pair. For example, I'd like all my rows in the table to have a key 'id' and a value for that ID.